# Suggest a list of allowed strings for prop values in Svelte and VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, svelte

I'm making a svelte library, and one of the components that'll be imported looks like this.

```
<Chart size="medium">{//code}</Chart>
```

The component looks like this.

```
<script>
    export let size = "medium" // "large" || "small";
</script>

<div>{//code}</div>
```

I want users to see a list of allowed strings as suggestions when using the component or a possible alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use TypeScript this will come out of the box, just define the prop correctly:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  export let size: "small" | "medium" | "large" = "medium";
</script>
```

When Svelte builds your library, it will create type definitions and everything for you that will then be picked up by consumers (normally even JavaScript users should benefit from this)

If you don't use TypeScript, you should at least use JavaScript with JSDoc

```
<script>
  /**
   * @type {("small" | "medium" | "large")}
   */
  export let size = 'medium';
</script>
```